# Tracking a Single Task on Multiple Boards in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, kanban

I am using VSTS's Kanban board to track tasks for a cross functional team.  Another PM needs to use one of my resources to complete a task on their board.   Ideally we would have the same card for this work on both of our kanban boards.  Me so that I could understand the workload on my team member, and them so that they can actually track the work being done.  Is there any way to have the same card or mirror cards show up on two different kanban boards in VSTS?

Comment: Wouldn't the only impact on your team be reduced capacity for that team member, which can be reflected in the Capacity assigned to them for that sprint?

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer is No.

No matter for which team members (including the another PM) change a work item status, the work item shows in Kanban board should be the same.

Such as if the PM change the work item to `complete` state, you will also find the work item in `complete` column.

For your situation, the PM can **create a new work item** for his/her own work. If the PM’s work item is related to your work item, then you can add the work item as a link for the new created work item: Related work -> Add link -> existing item -> select link type, such as related/child/parent etc -> find the work item need to link  -> OK.

[image]